Possible bug in RegionDistance when used with Rotate and Translate
While I was trying to solve this problem, I noticed a strange result of RegionDistance. The following is a contour plot of the distance from the tilted square. Is it a bug? Should I avoid using Translate to specify a region? It seems Rotate is OK in this case.
I'm using "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)".
Clear["Global`*"];
L = 10;
square = Rotate[Translate[Rectangle[-{L,L}/2, {L,L}/2], {3, -3}], 0.3];

dist = RegionDistance[square];

Show[ContourPlot[dist[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None], Graphics[{LightYellow, square}]]



I am using 14.1 Mac OS Sonoma and see the same thing. Interestingly if you increase the rotation the difference gets even bigger up to a maximum at Pi

Not a bug since  rotate  not always get a proper region (  for later version maybe fully support  all the graphics object be an region)

Edit
Finally we found that add the center {0, 0} in the Rotate do the job.
Clear["Global`*"];
L = 10;
square = 
  Rotate[Translate[Rectangle[-{L, L}/2, {L, L}/2], {3, -3}], 
   0.3, {0, 0} (*add here *)];

dist = RegionDistance[square];

Show[ContourPlot[dist[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None], Graphics[{LightYellow, square}]]


Edit

Compare with the five results, I confirm that upto 14.1 version, it is recommend that not use the Rotate as the last transformation.

Clear["Global`*"];
L = 10;
rectangle = Rectangle[-{L, L}/2, {L, L}/2];
square = Rotate[Translate[rectangle, {3, -3}], 0.3];
square2 = 
  GeometricTransformation[rectangle, 
   RotationTransform[.3]@*TranslationTransform[{3, -3}]];
square3 = 
  GeometricTransformation[rectangle, 
   TranslationTransform[RotationMatrix[.3] . {3, -3}]@*
    RotationTransform[.3]];
square4 = 
  TransformedRegion[rectangle, 
   RotationTransform[.3]@*TranslationTransform[{3, -3}]];
square5 = 
  TransformedRegion[rectangle, 
   RotationTransform[.3] . TranslationTransform[{3, -3}]];
dist = RegionDistance[square];
dist2 = RegionDistance[square2];
dist3 = RegionDistance[square3];
dist4 = RegionDistance[square4];
dist5 = RegionDistance[square5];
{ContourPlot[dist[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, square}],
 ContourPlot[dist2[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, square2}],
 ContourPlot[dist3[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, square3}], 
 ContourPlot[dist4[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, square4}], 
 ContourPlot[dist5[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, square5}]}


Original

Rotate at first.

Clear[square];
square = 
  Translate[Rotate[Rectangle[-{L, L}/2, {L, L}/2], .3], {3, -3}];
RegionQ[square]



Thank you. I will Rotate first for such cases. @Syed's answer suggests that TransformedRegion works as I expected (i.e. translate first, and then rotate). I wonder if Rotate is designed for  Graphic Primitives but not for Regions --- as you commented....

Very nice! Could you explain why just adding the center in the Rotate solves this problem?

@A.Kato  I still do not know why, but I found that Clear[a, b, t, square, squareX, dist, distX]; {a, b} = {4, 5}; t = .5; square = Rotate[Translate[rectangle, {a, b}], t, {a, b}]; squareX = Translate[Rotate[rectangle, t], {a, b}]; dist = RegionDistance[square]; distX = RegionDistance[squareX]; {ContourPlot[dist[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L},    Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, square}],   ContourPlot[distX[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L},    Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, squareX}]}  are the same.

Thank you for testing various codes. I ran your code (in your comment) with rectangle = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]. Then the result was different. It seems that RegionDistance ignores/forgets the fact that Rotate[g,t] will rotate graphics around the center of g, not the origin {0,0} of the coordinate system.

@A.Kato Thanks, you are right, we still need to add {0,0} in Rotate. L = 10; {a, b} = {4, 5}; t = .5; rectangle = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 1}]; square = Rotate[Translate[rectangle, {a, b}], t, {a, b}]; squareX =   Translate[Rotate[rectangle, t, {0, 0}], {a, b}]; dist =   RegionDistance[square]; distX =   RegionDistance[squareX]; {ContourPlot[   dist[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, Exclusions -> None,    Epilog -> {LightYellow, square}],   ContourPlot[distX[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L},    Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {LightYellow, squareX}]}

I am using v12.2.0.
Clear["Global`*"];
L = 10;
square = TransformedRegion[Rectangle[-{L, L}/2, {L, L}/2], 
   RotationTransform[0.3] . TranslationTransform[{3, -3}]];
dist = RegionDistance[square];
Show[ContourPlot[dist[{x, y}], {x, -L, 2 L}, {y, -2 L, L}, 
  Exclusions -> None], Graphics[{LightYellow, square}]]




Thank you very much. I learned that TransformdRegion is the appropriate tool here. Just to make sure, TransformdRegion[reg, A.B] applies first B, and then A. Am I right?

I can't say for sure. I deleted my previous comment as translation is not linear.

@A.Kato  RotationTransform[0.3] . TranslationTransform[{3, -3}] ==   AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[.3], RotationMatrix[.3] . {3, -3}}] , it means that RotationTransform[0.3] . TranslationTransform[{3, -3}]  is also a AffineTransform

@cvgmt, Thanks for the explanation and effort.

An attention should be payed on what the output of Rotate is. Rotate acts immediately on the expression no matter what the expression is.
So I recommend to use GeometricTransformation with RotationMatrix or RotationTransform for a serious manipulation of geometric objects.
Rotate[Translate[Rectangle[-{L, L}/2, {L, L}/2], {3, -3}], 0.3]
Translate[Rotate[Rectangle[-{L, L}/2, {L, L}/2], 0.3], {3, -3}]



